# How can I invoke a function with 3 outputs?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have create a method with 3 return value, but the problem is how can I invoke this method and assign it to 3 variables?

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void  random(out int num1, out int num2,out int num3)
    {

        int number1,number2,number3;
            Random ranNum = new Random();
            number1 = ranNum.Next(1, 7);
            number2 = ranNum.Next(1, 7);
            number3 = ranNum.Next(1, 7);

            num1 = number1;
            num2 = number2;
            num3 = number3;

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables before invoking the method (which returns void) and pass them as out parameters.  Alternatively you could create an another class, or an inner class, which has the values as properties and return an instance of that from the method.

```
 int num1;
 int num2;
 int num3;

 random(out num1, out num2, out num3);
```

or

```
public class RandomNumbers
{
    public int Num1 { get; set; }
    public int Num2 { get; set; }
    public int Num3 { get; set; }
}

...

public RandomNumbers random()
{
    Random ranNum = new Random();

    return new RandomNumbers
    {
        Num1 = ranNum.Next(1, 7),
        Num2 = ranNum.Next(1, 7),
        Num3 = ranNum.Next(1, 7),
    };

}
```

The other thing you could do is return a `Tuple` - though I tend to think that that syntax is generally awkward to use and would prefer a specific container type, something with more semantic meaning.

```
public Tuple<int,int,int> random()
{
    Random ranNum = new Random();

    return Tuple.Create(ranNum.Next(1, 7), ranNum.Next(1, 7), ranNum.Next(1, 7));
}
```

Comment: You don't need the out params in such case

Comment: thx ,its work and which method is more prefer to use , because i was just new in c#

Comment: I attempt to avoid `out` parameters, with the only exception being the `Try...` pattern, for example `int.TryParse(stringValue, out intValue)` or `dictionary.TryGet(key, out value)` where you want to know whether the operation was successful (those return `bool` as well as set the output value).  I'd probably create a class or, maybe, a struct to hold the values. As I said I find using the Tuple cumbersome and less readable, e.g., `tuple.Item1`

Comment: @Lenner90 I just think that functions (methods) shouldn't modify their parameters. The `out` keyword helps by making it obvious but generally I think it's a sign that you've got something wrong - like the method is trying to do more than one thing or you're missing a conceptual model.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n1, n2, n3
    random(out n1, out n2, out n3);
    // now n1, n2 and n3 has the output values
}
```

Since output parameters are not the best practice, you could better create a Result class and only return one object in your *random* function:

```
public class RandomResult
{
    public int n1 { get;set;}
    public int n2 { get;set;}
    public int n3 { get;set;}
}

public RandomResult random()
{
    RandomResult result = new RandomResult();
    Random ranNum = new Random();
    result.n1 = ranNum.Next(1, 7);
    result.n2 = ranNum.Next(1, 7);
    result.n3 = ranNum.Next(1, 7);
    return result;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RandomResult result = random();
    // now RandomResult.n1, RandomResult.n2 and RandomResult.n3 has the output values
}
```